# The functions called inside .then(data=> - will disappear within few seconds in react

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQ55F.jpg) I am trying to fetch data from the server when submitting the register button. While submitting the button it should be directed to the next page. I am getting a proper response from the server. However, when I am calling function or setState function it is directing to the next page but it will get disappear within seconds.  if I did console.log(data) it will show data in the console for a few seconds. Here is my code for fetch.

Comment: You should add more code, whole component probably. As text!

Answer (score 0):

```
then(response => {response.json()}.then(data => //.....)
```

You can only call `then` on a promise, meaning that `then(response =>{response.json()}` has to

a.) return something, which currently is `void` since you have brackets with no explicit `return` statement.

b.) have that something be a promise which then can be followed by a `then` clause.

```
.then(response => Promise.resolve(response.json()).then(data => //.....)
```